# Query with if statements inside do while loop in a password verification routine

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a password verification routine, my problem is when a input is entered it will go through each if statement individually. I'm trying to restart validation when a condition is not met. At the moment it only jumps to the next if statement when the previous condition is met, even though its a new input. I'm basically trying to get the loop to re run when one of the conditions is not met. At the moment it loops through individually. I tried the multiple next.() to try get back to the start of the verification.  Thanks in advance.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 


public class passWordCheck {
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
 
String passWord; // Initialize string for the password.
 
Scanner code = new Scanner(System.in);
// Give requirements for a valid password.
System.out.println("1. A code must contain no spaces");
System.out.println("2. A code must have between 5 and 10 characters (inclusive)");
System.out.println("3. A code must begin with \\ and must end with \\");
System.out.println("4. A code must contain at least one lowercase letter and at least one uppercase letter");
System.out.print("Please enter a code: ");
passWord = code.nextLine();
// Do While loop to check all requirement for a valid password are met.
do {
 
if (!firstCharacter(passWord)) {// Check First Character
    System.out.println("Code must start with \\.");
    System.out.println("Code is invalid, Please try again");
    passWord = code.nextLine();
}
if (!lastCharacter(passWord)) {// Check last Character
    System.out.println("Code must end with \\.");
    System.out.println("Code is invalid, Please try again");
    passWord = code.nextLine();
}
if (!hasCorrectLength(passWord)) {// Check password length
    System.out.println("Code must be between 5 and 15 characters in lenth.");
    System.out.println("Code is invalid, Please try again");
    passWord = code.nextLine();
}
if (!hasUpperCharacter(passWord)) {// Check for uppercase Character
    System.out.println("Code must contain at least one uppercase letter.");
    System.out.println("Code is invalid, Please try again");
    passWord = code.nextLine();
}
if (!hasLowerCharacter(passWord)) {// Check for lowercase character
    System.out.println("Code must contain at least one lowercase letter.");
    System.out.println("Code is invalid, Please try again");
    passWord = code.nextLine();
}
 
} while (false);
 
System.out.println("code is valid.");
code.close();
 
}
 
// Methods for checking password requirements
 
public static boolean firstCharacter(String str) {
 
char first = str.charAt(0); // First character of a string
 
if (first == ('\\')) // This verifies there is a \ at the start.
{
return true;
}
return false;
 
}
 
public static boolean lastCharacter(String str) {
 
int n = str.length(); // Finding string length
 
char last = str.charAt(n - 1); // Last character of a string
 
if (last == ('\\')) // This verifies there is a \ at the end.
{
return true;
}
return false;
 
}
 
public static boolean hasCorrectLength(String str) {
 
int n = str.length(); // Finding string length
 
if (n >= 5 || n <= 15) // This verifies the correct length.
{
return true;
}
 
return false;
}
 
public static boolean hasLowerCharacter(String str) {
 
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { // For loop to check password for lowercase
char currentCharacter = str.charAt(i);
if (Character.isLowerCase(currentCharacter)) {
return true;
}
}
return false;
 
}
 
public static boolean hasUpperCharacter(String str) {
 
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { // For loop to check password for uppercase
char currentCharacter = str.charAt(i);
if (Character.isUpperCase(currentCharacter)) {
return true;
}
 
}
return false;
 
}
 
}
```

Comment: You are asking the user for input in every if block: `passWord = code.nextLine();` If you don't want your program to stop at that point (Which waiting for user input will always do), then you cannot ask for user input at that moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, your loop effectively does nothing, since its loop-condition is never met, and you request a new password every time one of your checks fail, and **continue** the checks with the new password (not repeating the checking process), and after the last check you continue with the (possibly false) password.

You should make your loop-condition `true` to run forever, and `break;` out of it at the end if all checks ran correctly, and `continue;` the loop if one of your if-statements runs (meaning that *that* check failed). And to request a new password at the beginning and every time one of the checks fail, put `password = code.nextLine();` as the first statement in your loop, and remove every other instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Continue the loop on the basis of a value. Instead of using `while(false)` try `while(isValid)` where `isValid` is a boolean which if true if any of the conditions fail and false in case all the conditions pass.

Answer (score 0):

You should add else if statements to your conditions this way if one of them fails then it will do to the next line

```
while(code.hasNextLine()) {
   if (!firstCharacter(passWord)) {// Check First Character
       System.out.println("Code must start with \\.");
       System.out.println("Code is invalid, Please try again");
       passWord = code.nextLine();
   } else if (!lastCharacter(passWord)) {// Check last Character
   
   } //etc
   else {
       System.out.println("code/line is valid.");
   } 
}
```